# Keyboard and Mouse Don't work on USB 3.0 Dock

Tags: linux, ubuntu, usb, hid, displaylink

I purchased a [USB Dock from Sabrent](https://www.sabrent.com/product/DS-RICA/usb-3-0-universal-docking-station-stand-tablets-laptops/),
and after installing the [DisplayLink Driver](https://www.synaptics.com/products/displaylink-graphics/downloads/macos) with a addition of

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash usbcore.autosuspend=-1"
```

to grubs config.
After this I got it up and running, the second screen comes on, although it lags terribly it works, or so I thought.

For some reason, no USB keyboard or mouse I plug into the Hub works as intended.

- Aluminum Apple Keyboard does not light up or turn on.
- Razer Naga Mouse Lights up, and the keyboard on the side works, but mouse does not move.

But a Razer Kraken USB Headset works as intended?

Iv looked though google to try and figure this out, and tried several things. One of which was trying to disable UEFI on the Bios, and my Mobo (Asus M5A78L-L USB3) does not even have that option.

Iv also tried disabling Legacy USB from BIOS with no change.

Weird bit is, the mouse shows up under lsusb and dmesg shows no problems I can see.

Mouse plugged into Dock: (Dmesg)

```
[5312.360339] usb 8-2.3.4: new full-speed USB device number 16 using xhci_hcd
[ 5312.698367] usb 8-2.3.4: New USB device found, idVendor=1532, idProduct=0053, bcdDevice= 2.00
[ 5312.698380] usb 8-2.3.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ 5312.698386] usb 8-2.3.4: Product: Razer Naga Chroma
[ 5312.698390] usb 8-2.3.4: Manufacturer: Razer
[ 5312.708921] input: Razer Razer Naga Chroma as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.0/0000:03:00.0/usb8/8-2/8-2.3/8-2.3.4/8-2.3.4:1.0/0003:1532:0053.0040/input/input141
[ 5312.774984] hid-generic 0003:1532:0053.0040: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [Razer Razer Naga Chroma] on usb-0000:03:00.0-2.3.4/input0
[ 5312.777379] input: Razer Razer Naga Chroma Keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.0/0000:03:00.0/usb8/8-2/8-2.3/8-2.3.4/8-2.3.4:1.1/0003:1532:0053.0041/input/input142
[ 5312.836533] input: Razer Razer Naga Chroma Consumer Control as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.0/0000:03:00.0/usb8/8-2/8-2.3/8-2.3.4/8-2.3.4:1.1/0003:1532:0053.0041/input/input143
[ 5312.836628] input: Razer Razer Naga Chroma System Control as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.0/0000:03:00.0/usb8/8-2/8-2.3/8-2.3.4/8-2.3.4:1.1/0003:1532:0053.0041/input/input144
[ 5312.836710] input: Razer Razer Naga Chroma as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.0/0000:03:00.0/usb8/8-2/8-2.3/8-2.3.4/8-2.3.4:1.1/0003:1532:0053.0041/input/input145
[ 5312.836806] hid-generic 0003:1532:0053.0041: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [Razer Razer Naga Chroma] on usb-0000:03:00.0-2.3.4/input1
[ 5312.837413] input: Razer Razer Naga Chroma as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.0/0000:03:00.0/usb8/8-2/8-2.3/8-2.3.4/8-2.3.4:1.2/0003:1532:0053.0042/input/input146
[ 5312.897090] hid-generic 0003:1532:0053.0042: input,hidraw2: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [Razer Razer Naga Chroma] on usb-0000:03:00.0-2.3.4/input2
```

Mouse plugged into PC: (Dmesg)

```
[5324.276234] usb 6-2: new full-speed USB device number 12 using ohci-pci
[ 5324.504637] usb 6-2: New USB device found, idVendor=1532, idProduct=0053, bcdDevice= 2.00
[ 5324.504649] usb 6-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ 5324.504655] usb 6-2: Product: Razer Naga Chroma
[ 5324.504659] usb 6-2: Manufacturer: Razer
[ 5324.511504] input: Razer Razer Naga Chroma as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:13.1/usb6/6-2/6-2:1.0/0003:1532:0053.0043/input/input147
[ 5324.511821] hid-generic 0003:1532:0053.0043: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [Razer Razer Naga Chroma] on usb-0000:00:13.1-2/input0
[ 5324.515645] input: Razer Razer Naga Chroma Keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:13.1/usb6/6-2/6-2:1.1/0003:1532:0053.0044/input/input148
[ 5324.572516] input: Razer Razer Naga Chroma Consumer Control as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:13.1/usb6/6-2/6-2:1.1/0003:1532:0053.0044/input/input149
[ 5324.572666] input: Razer Razer Naga Chroma System Control as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:13.1/usb6/6-2/6-2:1.1/0003:1532:0053.0044/input/input150
[ 5324.572789] input: Razer Razer Naga Chroma as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:13.1/usb6/6-2/6-2:1.1/0003:1532:0053.0044/input/input151
[ 5324.572902] hid-generic 0003:1532:0053.0044: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [Razer Razer Naga Chroma] on usb-0000:00:13.1-2/input1
[ 5324.622050] input: Razer Razer Naga Chroma as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:13.1/usb6/6-2/6-2:1.2/0003:1532:0053.0045/input/input152
[ 5324.699441] hid-generic 0003:1532:0053.0045: input,hidraw2: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [Razer Razer Naga Chroma] on usb-0000:00:13.1-2/input2
```

The mouse shows up in xinput list:

```
Virtual core pointer                        id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Razer Razer Naga Chroma Consumer Control  id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Razer Razer Naga Chroma                   id=17   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Razer Razer Kraken 7.1 Chroma Consumer Control    id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Razer Razer Kraken 7.1 Chroma             id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Apple Inc. Apple Keyboard                 id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Apple Inc. Apple Keyboard                 id=16   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Razer Razer Naga Chroma Keyboard          id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Razer Razer Naga Chroma                   id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Razer Razer Naga Chroma System Control    id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Razer Razer Naga Chroma Consumer Control  id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

THey keyboard does have a problem in dmesg, that i think relates to the fact that it has its on inbuilt hub in it aswell.
dmesg when keyboard plugged into Dock:

```
[ 4974.159538] usb 8-2.3.3: new high-speed USB device number 15 using xhci_hcd
[ 4974.372112] usb 8-2.3.3: New USB device found, idVendor=05ac, idProduct=1006, bcdDevice=96.15
[ 4974.372124] usb 8-2.3.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 4974.372130] usb 8-2.3.3: Product: Keyboard Hub
[ 4974.372134] usb 8-2.3.3: Manufacturer: Apple, Inc.
[ 4974.372138] usb 8-2.3.3: SerialNumber: 000000000000
[ 4974.377886] hub 8-2.3.3:1.0: USB hub found
[ 4974.377976] hub 8-2.3.3:1.0: 3 ports detected
[ 4974.479678] hub 8-2.3.3:1.0: hub_ext_port_status failed (err = -71)
[ 4974.605591] usb 8-2.3.3: USB disconnect, device number 15
```

Keyboard when plugged into PC:

```
[ 4988.519415] usb 2-6: new high-speed USB device number 14 using ehci-pci
[ 4988.684291] usb 2-6: New USB device found, idVendor=05ac, idProduct=1006, bcdDevice=96.15
[ 4988.684300] usb 2-6: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 4988.684304] usb 2-6: Product: Keyboard Hub
[ 4988.684306] usb 2-6: Manufacturer: Apple, Inc.
[ 4988.684308] usb 2-6: SerialNumber: 000000000000
[ 4988.684587] hub 2-6:1.0: USB hub found
[ 4988.684655] hub 2-6:1.0: 3 ports detected
[ 4988.979406] usb 2-6.2: new low-speed USB device number 15 using ehci-pci
[ 4989.098659] usb 2-6.2: New USB device found, idVendor=05ac, idProduct=024f, bcdDevice= 0.74
[ 4989.098672] usb 2-6.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ 4989.098677] usb 2-6.2: Product: Apple Keyboard
[ 4989.098681] usb 2-6.2: Manufacturer: Apple Inc.
[ 4989.104055] input: Apple Inc. Apple Keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:13.2/usb2/2-6/2-6.2/2-6.2:1.0/0003:05AC:024F.003E/input/input139
[ 4989.164002] apple 0003:05AC:024F.003E: input,hidraw3: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [Apple Inc. Apple Keyboard] on usb-0000:00:13.2-6.2/input0
[ 4989.167119] apple 0003:05AC:024F.003F: Fn key not found (Apple Wireless Keyboard clone?), disabling Fn key handling
[ 4989.167254] input: Apple Inc. Apple Keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:13.2/usb2/2-6/2-6.2/2-6.2:1.1/0003:05AC:024F.003F/input/input140
[ 4989.223701] apple 0003:05AC:024F.003F: input,hidraw4: USB HID v1.11 Device [Apple Inc. Apple Keyboard] on usb-0000:00:13.2-6.2/input1
```

I'm currently running Ubuntu 20.04.

I'm out of ideas. Help.

Update: tried dock and cable on windows laptop. Works fine. No lag on display, mouse works as intended, headphones are on. Seems to be a problem only with linux.

Comment: I have a similar problem, and it's not cables. My hunch is that the USB2 devices (keyboard, mouse) stop working (/working properly) once USB3 is activated. But I don't have a fix :-(

Answer (score 0):

I suspect a problem with the cable, did you try different cables to connect the dock to the PC?

It sounds like the USB link is bandwidth limited, as indicated by high lag in the video and the keyboard and mouse showing as connected but unresponsive.  They appear to be getting power and some USB data through but at a rate so slow that nothing is working as it should.

You will have to use a cable that supports USB 3.0 or better (USB 3.1, 3.2, etc., hereafter I'll call USB 3.x).  I've seen people use USB 2.0 cables, or USB 3.x cables that were cheaply made and so were effectively USB 2.0, on docks like this and get the behavior you described.  If you used a cable different than that included with the dock then that might explain it.

USB 3.x compliant cables will have the "superspeed" stylized "SS" and the USB "trident" icon.  Newer USB 3.x cables often have a number showing the minimum tested bandwidth in Gbps, the number will be a 5, 10, 20, or 40.  There's some non-compliant cables with these icons on them but they are rare.  It turns out that it is illegal to use someone's trademark without permission but not illegal to sell crappy cables, people that break the law tend to go out of business faster than those that sell cheap cables that don't work.

USB 3.x has a passive cable length limit of one meter, so if your cable is longer than this then it breaks the spec or is an expensive repeater cable.  If you bought a repeater cable then you'd likely be aware of this, the price of the cable should have been a clue.  If you are using the cable that came with the dock then try a different cable if you have one you can borrow from another device or have one sitting in a drawer.  Check the cable with another device if you can.  If you have to buy a cable to test this theory then double check that it is compliant with the USB 3.x spec before you buy, that is look for the USB icon and so on.  Replacement cables should not cost too much, often $8 online or $15 at a brick-n-mortar store.

One other thing I can suggest is if you bought a USB-C to USB-B cable for the dock then try flipping over the USB-C end of the cable.  USB-C cables are supposed to work either side up but a cheap or damaged cable might have a bad data path on only one side, flipping it over could connect the working portion of the cable.

Best I can tell it looks like you did a fair job ruling out software issues which leaves hardware issues.  Most often hardware failure is in the cable which is fortunately cheap and easy to fix.  If the cable can be ruled out then maybe the dock is damaged.

Comment: Ok. Tried a shorter cable. No dice. Tried the whole setup on my wifes laptop running windows. Works perfectly. Same cable same dock.

Comment: @StevenVenham Are you sure the Ubuntu computer has USB 3.x ports and the correct drivers for those ports?  Are other USB 3.x devices working as expected in those same ports?  This looks like a bandwidth problem, make sure the data can get through fast enough for all devices.